# screen brightness changing issue in change plan setting using c# code

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

I am trying to set the screen brightness using `WmiSetBrightness` method.

The brightness is changed in the setting and control panel but the didn't change the below location `Control Panel\Hardware` and `Sound\Power` Options inside change plan setting.

Please help me

how I can change the change plan setting using C# code ?

Comment: static void SetBrightness(byte targetBrightness) {
    ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope("root\\WMI");
    SelectQuery query = new SelectQuery("WmiMonitorBrightnessMethods");
    using(ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query)) {
        using(ManagementObjectCollection objectCollection = searcher.Get()) {
            foreach(ManagementObject mObj in objectCollection) {
                mObj.InvokeMethod("WmiSetBrightness",
                    new Object[] { UInt32.MaxValue, targetBrightness });
                break;

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow! Please take your time and read through the following article: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . It will help you to improve your question, making it more likely that people will respond.